# Rails 3 scaffold error with 7 value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hello when i write `rails g scaffold Post one:string two:string three:string five:string six:string seven:string eight:string`  when i want to put text into seven field it gives me decimal not string. Where is the problem? thanks

Comment: Show your migration code

Comment: In your code there is no any problem

Comment: Seven questions, no accepted answers... try accepting some answers on previous questions, and I am sure that others will be more likely to help you.